# Error while running artisan command from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backup

while running below artisan command from controller works fine

```
Artisan::call('backup:run');
```

but why this is not working

```
Artisan::call('backup:run --only-db');
```

it throws error The command "backup:run --only-db" does not exist.

through CLI it works fine

```
php artisan backup:db --only-db
```

Comment: finally got a solution  Artisan::call('backup:run', [ '--only-db' => true ]);

Comment: There's no need to modiy title. If you solved your problem - __write an answer__ and __accept__ it.

Comment: The documentation for Milian answer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you wanted to do is.

```
Artisan::call('backup:run',['--only-db'=>true]);
```